# Meld does not allow me to edit files in left and right panels

Tags: meld, mergetool

I used **Meld** as a megetool for a couple of years and everything was fine.
To complete a conflict resolution I had to make **all three** panels content identical.

I was able to edit ALL THREE panels and eventually I end up with some solution.

After moving to another laptop and reinstalling the Meld I'm no longer able to edit left and right panel. They are read only. I can only edit a central one and put code pieces into it.

Am I missing some configuration? It is a version change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some shenanigans my meld is back to normal.
If anyone hit the very same problem - there is no need to reinstall OS or something.

I've removed meld, tried to use kdiff3. I didn't like it and removed it, then installed meld again and, a miracle happened, it works as it was before.

used brew for mostly all steps.

one unusual command I've used was
brew **re**install meld